# Divided a string by one of a few options

Tags: c, strtok

I have a `char` array in which I would like to loop, where its divided by all math operations ,

for example, right now I am looking only for `=` sign , so

```
   for (char *p = strtok(data,"="); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        numberOfChars++;
    }
```

I would like to loop where not only `"="` is the token , but it could be one of these also : `+,-,*,\,=`

so that we increment in a loop the `numberOfChars` for every one of these.

so for  : `a = b + c` we will get **3** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can symply loop through the string

```
for (size_t i=0; i < strlen(data); i++)
    {
        if ((data[i] == '+') || 
            (data[i] == '-') || 
            (data[i] == '*') || 
            (data[i] == '\') || 
            (data[i] == '='))
        {
            numberOfChars++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a *set of delimiter tokens* as the `delim`.

From the `C11` standard, chapter §7.24.5.8

> `char *strtok(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);`
>
> A sequence of calls to the strtok function breaks the string pointed to by s1 into a
>   sequence of tokens, **each of which is delimited by a character from the string pointed to
>   by `s2`.** [....]

So, in your case, if you want to tokenize the input string using *any* of the tokens from `=+-*/`, you should use something like

```
char * delim = "=+-*/`";
.
.
char *p = strtok(data, delim);
```

**NOTE:** As mentioned by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) in the comments, please be aware,

> *Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that: These functions modify their first argument. These functions cannot be used on constant strings.The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.*

---

On another alternative approach, if you're counting the number of operators in a mathematical statement, simply you can loop over the array and use `isdigit()`/ `isspace()` t0 find out the non-digit entries and update the counter.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you elaborate on these? show some relevant simple example ?

Comment: I think that it is necessary to leave the delimiter.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sir, isn't it only about getting the count or did I miss something?

Comment: At least I think we should note that `strtok` is destructive.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY done. Also added an alternative for non-destructive approach. :)